# Mongodb native driver chain queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, subquery

I am new to queries in mongodb. I have a document like this -

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5eb0f70f88cd051e7839325c"), 
   "id" : "1", 
   "arrayInfo" : [ {"color":"red"}, {"color":"black"}, {"color":"cyan"} ] 
}
```

There are many documents in this format with changing ids and colors inside arrayInfo. I want to do something like -

Find record with id "1" -> Display object inside array info with {"color" : "cyan"}

I believe I have to chain queries after finding like this -

```
db.collection('Records').findOne({id:"1"}).**something**
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: did you try just find() method

Comment: find({}) returns a cursor of all matched records. I just need one so I use findOne but I specifically need access to that record's arrayInfo array.

Comment: oh i think this will not work for deep search in mongo db

Comment: why are you not passing document id ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge,that is not in anyway related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(id===1){

res.arrayInfo.map(item => console.log(item.color))
}
```

```js
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { $elemMatch: { qty: 5, warehouse: "A" } } } )
```

[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

Comment: I read the mongodb document and this does not answer my question. I have specifically mentioned that I am trying to access the property of a found object.

Comment: use query to find document when you find your specfic document then get the data with js

Comment: That defeats the entire purpose of this question. I need to use mongodb queries for this.

Answer (score 0):

If no operator is specified, MongoDB by default performs array element matching when the document stores an array. Thus you can simply do:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.findOne({id:'1',arrayInfo:{color:'cyan'}})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb0f70f88cd051e7839325c"),
        "id" : "1",
        "arrayInfo" : [
                {
                        "color" : "red"
                },
                {
                        "color" : "black"
                },
                {
                        "color" : "cyan"
                }
        ]
}
```

To match one field in the array instead of the complete array element, use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).